# Share bookmarks to local files (file: protocol ones) between computers

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I work with multiple computers and OS'es at work and regularly use a number of HTML reference documents. To save time and bandwidth, I saved those to disk.

However, the bookmarks for these local copies have hardcoded paths which means when I synchronize the bookmarks (and the files) between computers, they would only work under one computer because the file system structure is different on each one.

So I need a way to embed some kind of per-device path into the bookmarks or similar solutions.

### Stuff I've tried

- Relative paths -- doesn't work
- Create a `C:` folder under the root (`/`) directory of the Macs and the Linux computers. This works, but is very ugly.
- Setup a local HTTP server on each computer. This works but requires a lot of configuration. I am not allowed to do this on some of the work computers.

### Something I am trying

I could have a website that would redirect me back to a local (file://) URL according to the computer that is requesting it. It feels like people must have done this before. I am just wonder does anyone know anything like this?

Comment: Maybe for the relative paths idea, you could incorporate symbolic links on each computer to point the bookmark path to the correct location on disk? I think a better idea would be to use a JavaScript bookmarklet which could detect your computer and then load the proper path. :)

Comment: I thought about symbolic links, but you'll still have to use an absolute paths in `file://` URLs to get to the symbolic link first :(  Javascript booklets are difficult to write, use and update though...

Comment: I struggle with this constantly; agree that faux drive letters on Un*x systems feels awfully ugly. The redirect idea is interesting but would only work online - kind of a bummer for local files.

Comment: Relative paths would be my solution.  What's the problem with them?  Do you get an error message?  If the browser is trying to visit the wrong URL, what does it get wrong, i.e. what do you get in the location bar v.s. what you want it to be?

Comment: @sourcejedi The problem is browsers do not accept relative URLs relative to no where. I.e. they only work within a "current" page. I.e. "[file://]../../folder" does not go anywhere if entered directly in the address bar or put in a bookmark.

Comment: Ah.  I was thinking of something like a manually-created index page.  Which would not be wonderfully convenient; it's just probably the simplest thing that could work :).